# how to inject hotjar in angular 8 app as hotjar and npm is giving different methods?

Tags: angular8, implementation, hotjar

I got the tracking code from hotjar and it is instruction is not working. I am trying to implement hotjar in a single-page app. The tracking code is a script and npm is giving this method to implement it.

```
import { NgxHotjarModule } from 'ngx-hotjar';


imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxHotjarModule.forRoot('traking-code')
]
```

Comment: I'm still looking for solution

Comment: I implemented using the CDN with the script tag they provide. It records my screens and movements but I do not see the actual content, only the loader. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

tracking code is a number on the site. See Site ID: [image: hotjar tracking code for single page]

```
NgxHotjarModule.forRoot('1821XXXX'),
```